# can indexOf work on an updating array?

Tags: javascript

I [understand that there are ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array) to get unique elements in an array. This question isn't asking about that. This question is asking why `indexOf` returns `-1` for "kale" in the `unique_vegetables` array once it's already been added. Is there something about `indexOf` that makes it not work in this situation?

```
    var vegetables = ["kale", "broccoli", "kale"];

    function produce(){
       var unique_vegetables = [];
       unique_vegetables = vegetables.map(function(v){
        if (v.length > 0){  //irrelevant check to make sure the string has characters
             var k = unique_vegetables.indexOf(v);
            return k < 0 ? v : null;
        }else {
             return null;
        }
       })
       return unique_vegetables;
    }

    var t = produce();
    console.log(t, "unique vegetables")  ///  ["kale", "broccoli", "kale"]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/g6nn9nn6/

Comment: Why dont you *filter*?

Comment: _why indexOf returns -1_, because `unique_vegetables` is `[]` just put a console

Comment: Because `v.length > 0` is true always and `unique_vegetables.indexOf(v)` is always `-1` as array is empty. So you are returning same value. Are you trying to achieve [this](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/g6nn9nn6/1/)?

Comment: @Satpal but is unique_vegetables still [] when the second instance of "kale" maps?

Comment: @Leahcim Yes. `unique_vegetables` will be updated when `.map` returns the value. You are returning from `Callback` to `.map`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unique values in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vegetables.forEach(function(v){
    if (v.length > 0){ 
         var k = unique_vegetables.indexOf(v);
        if(k < 0) unique_vegetables.push(v);
    }
})
```

unique_vegetables is an empty array until the map function finished and returned, so you need to change unique_vegetables while iterating.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using `Array.map`, there are 3 things that make it a whole.

- Callback function
- Return statement inside callback
- Return from `.map`

`Callback` is the function that will be called on every iteration and will be passed 3 arguments viz., currentElement, index, and array itself.

`Return from callback` will initialize the value of this iteration in return array. This return array is a local array in `.map` and will not be accessible to you.

`Return from map` is the final step that returns the parsed local array pointed out in previous step.

`Array.map` would look something like this in simple implementation:

```js
function myMap(arr, callback){
  var temp = [];
  for(var i = 0; i< arr.length; i++){
    temp[i] = callback(arr[i], i, arr);
  }
  return temp;
}

var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
var b = myMap(a, function(n, i, a){ return n * 2 })
console.log(b)
```

#### Reference

- [Polyfill - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example#Polyfill): You can refer it to check the actual code.